# Getting information about the CVS server from CVS checkout files

Tags: svn, cvs, cvs2svn

I have CVS checkout files. I am trying to migrate  into  SVN repository keeping the history of CVS.How can I get the information for its migration from the CVS checkout files so that i can keep track of CVS repository?

Answer (score 1):

As @khmarbaise says, to keep a record of the old CVS revision numbers in SVN, use the [`--cvs-revnums`](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2svn.html#cmd-ref) flag when converting.

Keeping the CVS revision numbers as an SVN property on the revision seems like a good idea but in my experience they never get used.  SVN properties will also remain associated with the file unless they are explicitly deleted which means that they over time they tend to become inaccurate for new SVN revisions as *no one* will ever delete them.  If needed, I suggest you keep the old CVS repository files around for reference, there is no need to keep running the CVS server, you can just point to the CVS root on the file system from any CVS client.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is an option in cvs2svn which stores the CVS revision in an SVN property. But after migration there is no way back. This is a oneway.